# Task Queue API: ETA and Countdown

Tags: google-app-engine, queue, task, task-queue

I love the new TaskQueue API.

I have a question about the ETA/Countdown, if I set it a new Task to execute 10 minutes in the future and it is the only item in the queue - will it execute in roughly 10 minutes or will it execute straight away?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will execute **no sooner** than 10 minutes from now (it may execute later if the queue is full, naturally).